# wx Python Gui start up too slow?

Tags: python, wxpython

the code below is quite incomplete. but I want to check some stuff for errors.... thing is when I compile it.... nothing happens after it starts up. anything I did wrong here? I also check the task manager and see it in the background, but the gui never pops up.

```
from wx import *
import Order as o
import OrderItem as oi
import Customer as c
import Item as i
class OrderMain ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
            wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Orders", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 517,486 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

            self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.Size( -1,-1 ), wx.DefaultSize )

            bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

            #create the order item here
            self.ord = o.Order()

            self.list = wx.ListCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.LC_REPORT )
            self.list.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 500,300 ) )
            self.list.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 1000,800 ) )
            self.list.InsertColumn(0,"Order ID")
            self.list.InsertColumn(1,"Customer ID")
            self.list.InsertColumn(2,"Order Price")
            self.list.InsertColumn(3,"Order Date")
            self.list.Bind(EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED,self.GetSelectedItems)
            self.refresh_list(None)
            bSizer3.Add( self.list, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            bSizer4 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

            self.m_button20 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Add Order", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_button20.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_entry)
            bSizer4.Add( self.m_button20, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.m_button21 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Update Record", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_button21.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.show_entry)
            bSizer4.Add( self.m_button21, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5 )

            bSizer3.Add( bSizer4, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.SetSizer( bSizer3 )
            self.Layout()

            self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def refresh_list(self, event):
        """Place the names of each ItemEntry into the list"""

        self.index = 0
        self.entrydict = {}
        self.list.DeleteAllItems()
        for entry in self.ord.list_entries():
            self.list.InsertStringItem(self.index,entry.Order_ID)
            self.list.SetStringItem(self.index,1,entry.Cust_ID)
            self.list.SetStringItem(self.index,2,str(entry.Order_Price))
            self.list.SetStringItem(self.index,3,str(entry.Order_Date))
            self.entrydict[self.index] = entry
            self.index += 1


    def GetSelectedItems(self, event):
        """    Gets the selected items for the list control.
        Selection is returned as a list of selected indices,
        low to high.
        """
        selection = []
        self.index = self.list.GetFirstSelected()
        selection.append(self.index)
        while len(selection) != self.list.GetSelectedItemCount():
            self.index = self.list.GetNextSelected(self.index)
            selection.append(self.index)

        return self.index


    def add_entry(self, event):
        """Add a new entry to the Order_Date ite"""
        # start out with blank, generic ItemEntry
        entry = o.OrderEntry("","","0","")
        self.endiag = OrderDetail(self,entry)
        self.endiag.ShowModal()           



        self.ord.add_entry(entry.Order_ID,
                            entry.Cust_ID,
                            str(entry.Order_Price),
                            str(entry.Order_Date) )

        self.refresh_list(None)

    def show_entry(self, event):
        """updates the details of the currently selected entry"""
        e_id = self.index
        entry = self.ord.list_entries()[e_id]
        self.endiag2 = OrderDetailU(self , entry)
        self.endiag2.ShowModal()

        self.refresh_list(None)

    def __del__( self ):
            pass


class OrderDetail ( wx.Dialog ):

    def __init__( self, parent ,entry):
            wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Order Details", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,500 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )

            self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.Size( 500,500 ), wx.DefaultSize )
            self.entry = entry
            bSizer22 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
            self.ordite = oi.OrderItem()
            self.cust = c.Customer()
            gSizer6 = wx.GridSizer( 2, 2, 0, 0 )
            self.ordite=oi.OrderItem()

            self.m_staticText28 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Order ID", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText28.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText28, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            self.Order_ID = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,TE_PROCESS_ENTER )
            self.Order_ID.Bind(EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.setID)
            self.Order_ID.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,-1 ) )

            gSizer6.Add( self.Order_ID, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.m_staticText29 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Customer", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText29.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText29, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            m_choice1Choices = self.cust.list_entries()
            self.Cust_ID = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 200,-1 ), m_choice1Choices, 0 )
            self.Cust_ID.SetSelection( 0 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.Cust_ID, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            self.m_staticText18 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Order Price", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText18.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText18, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.computePrice()
            self.m_staticText19 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, str(self.entry.Order_Price), wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText19.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText19, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )


            self.m_staticText33 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Date", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText33.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText33, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.Order_Date = wx.DatePickerCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultDateTime, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.DP_DEFAULT )
            gSizer6.Add( self.Order_Date, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )


            bSizer22.Add( gSizer6, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            bSizer24 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

            self.m_staticText32 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Items", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText32.Wrap( -1 )
            bSizer24.Add( self.m_staticText32, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            self.list2 = wx.ListCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( -1,100 ), wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_SORT_DESCENDING )
            self.list2.InsertColumn(0,"Item ID")
            self.list2.InsertColumn(1,"Item Price")
            self.list2.InsertColumn(2,"Item Qty")
            self.list2.Bind(EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED,self.GetSelectedItems2)
            self.refresh_list2(None)
            bSizer24.Add( self.list2, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            gSizer7 = wx.GridSizer( 2, 2, 0, 0 )

            self.m_button17 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Add Item", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 100,-1 ), 0 )
            gSizer7.Add( self.m_button17, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            self.m_button18 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Delete Item", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 100,-1 ), 0 )
            gSizer7.Add( self.m_button18, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            bSizer24.Add( gSizer7, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            bSizer22.Add( bSizer24, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            gSizer8 = wx.GridSizer( 2, 2, 0, 0 )

            self.m_button19 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Ok", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 100,-1 ), 0 )
            gSizer8.Add( self.m_button19, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            self.m_button20 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Cancel", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 100,-1 ), 0 )
            gSizer8.Add( self.m_button20, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            bSizer22.Add( gSizer8, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.SetSizer( bSizer22 )
            self.Layout()

            self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def setID(self, event):
            entry.Order_ID = str(self.Order_ID.GetValue())

            return self.Order_ID


    def closeDial(self,event):
        """Closes the Dialog"""
        self.Destroy()

    def ComputePrice(self,event):

        for entry in self.ordite.list_entries():
                if self.ordite.OrderItemEntry.Order_ID == self.entry.Order_ID:
                        self.entry.Order_Price = self.entry.Order_Price + self.ordite.OrderItemEntry.Item_Price

        return self.entry.Order_Price
    def refresh_list2(self, event):
        """Place the names of each ItemEntry into the list"""

        self.index2 = 0
        self.entrydict = {}
        self.list2.DeleteAllItems()
        for entry in self.ordite.list_entries():
                if self.ordite.OrderItemEntry.Order_ID==self.entry.Order_ID:
                    self.list2.InsertStringItem(self.index,entry.Order_ID)
                    self.list2.SetStringItem(self.index,1,entry.Item_ID)
                    self.list2.SetStringItem(self.index,2,str(entry.Item_Price))
                    self.list2.SetStringItem(self.index,3,str(entry.Item_Qty))
                    self.entrydict[self.index2] = entry
                    self.index2 += 1


    def GetSelectedItems2(self, event):
        """    Gets the selected items for the list control.
        Selection is returned as a list of selected indices,
        low to high.
        """
        selection2 = []
        self.index2 = self.list2.GetFirstSelected()
        selection.append(self.index2)
        while len(selection2) != self.list2.GetSelectedItemCount():
            self.index = self.list2.GetNextSelected(self.index2)
            selection2.append(self.index2)

        return self.index2


    def add_item(self, event):
        """Add a new entry to the Order_Date ite"""
        # start out with blank, generic Entry
        entryit = oi.OrderItemEntry("","","","")
        self.endiag = AddItemOrder(self,entryit)
        self.endiag.ShowModal()           



        self.ordite.add_entry(entry.Order_ID,
                            entry.Cust_ID,
                            str(entry.Order_Price),
                            str(entry.Order_Date) )

        self.refresh_list(None)

    def ok(self, event):
        """sets the details of the current entry"""
        self.entry.set_details( str(self.Order_ID.GetValue()),
                            str(self.Cust_ID.GetValue()),
                            str(self.Order_Price.GetValue()),
                            str(self.Order_Date) )
        self.Destroy()

    def __del__( self ):
            pass


class AddItemOrder ( wx.Dialog ):

    def __init__( self, parent,entryit ):
            wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Add Item", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 285,173 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )
            self.entryit = entryit
            self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

            bSizer25 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

            gSizer9 = wx.GridSizer( 2, 2, 0, 0 )

            self.m_staticText34 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Item ID", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText34.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer9.Add( self.m_staticText34, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            m_choice2Choices = i.list_entries()
            self.Item_ID = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, m_choice2Choices, 0 )
            self.Item_ID.SetSelection( 0 )
            gSizer9.Add( self.Item_ID, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            self.m_staticText35 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Item Qty", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText35.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer9.Add( self.m_staticText35, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.Item_Qty = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 120,-1 ), 0 )
            gSizer9.Add( self.Item_Qty, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            bSizer25.Add( gSizer9, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.m_button19 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Ok", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            bSizer25.Add( self.m_button19, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.SetSizer( bSizer25 )
            self.Layout()

            self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def __del__( self ):
            pass


def main():

    ex = wx.App()
    OrderMain(None)
    ex.MainLoop()    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Show` your frame:

```
def main():

    ex = wx.App()
    frame = OrderMain(None)
    ex.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show()
    ex.MainLoop()
```